# How to add a custom field to a list item attachment?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, attachment

In a SharePoint 2010 development project (in VS 2010), we need to add a custom field to the list item attachments. For example, the user has an additional boolean field next to the attachment file browser similar to the below mockup:

[image: custom field for a list item attachment]

Any ideas?